# How to take multiple inputs with specific trim times to one output, single command ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to make a single ffmpeg command that will take multiple inputs, seek specific times within them, then output to a single file.

For example, I have `inputA.avi` and `inputB.avi` and each is 1 hour long. I want a single output file that takes `inputA.avi` from 00:00:00 to 00:20:00 for the beginning and `inputB.avi` from 00:00:00 to 00:10:00 for the end. The end result should be a 30 minute video file that has the first 20 minutes of `inputA` then the first 10 minutes of `inputB`.

I currently can do the following three commands to get the job done:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:20:00 -i inputA.avi [rest of command] inputA-trim.avi
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:10:00 -i inputB.avi [rest of command] inputB-trim.avi
ffmpeg -f concat -i inputList.txt [rest of command] final.mp4
```

where inputList.txt contains only

```
file inputA-trim.avi
file inputB-trim.avi
```

This works, but has unnecessary steps and creates intermediary files. I also have to create a batch file and txt file to get everything to run in succession. I'd like to be able to create a single ffmpeg command that can take multiple inputs with individual `-ss` and `-t` commands, then put them in a single output.

Comment: [This question seemed to be asking for close to the same thing](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/20985/extract-multiples-images-from-multiples-videos-with-ffmpeg), but the OP accepted a solution that essentially is what I am doing with the three commands in my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**#1** Using concat filter i.e. without textfile

```
ffmpeg -ss 0 -t 20:00 -i inputA.avi -ss 0 -t 10:00 -i inputB.avi -filter_complex "[0:v][0:a][1:v][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1" out.mp4
```

--OR--

**#2** Using concat demuxer i.e. with textfile

```
file inputA-trim.avi
inpoint 0
outpoint 20:00
file inputB-trim.avi
inpoint 0
outpoint 10:00
```

and then your final command

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i inputList.txt [rest of command] final.mp4
```

---

See https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate for details.

Comment: I have tested the second option listed, with the input txt file. I had to add `-safe 0` to avoid an "unsafe filename" error. The final command I used was `ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i inputList.txt -vf "scale=1280:720,setsar=1" -crf 30 -an -movflags +faststart final.mp4`. I'll test the first option some other time. Thanks.

Comment: I guess I had to use `-safe 0` because I had absolute full paths in my input txt file.

Comment: I've been using the first option for some time now. Just noticed I mentioned I would test it, but never reported back.

Comment: Does the concat filter re-encode?

Comment: The concat filter will require a re-encode. All frame filters will lead to a re-encode.